# Ember.js jquery cycle slideshow: zero elements found error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js, jquery-cycle

I am converting a html site to an Ember.js app and have run into an issue with the jQuery Cycle slideshow plugin. I have around 10 slideshows on the site, so I want to have one partial which I can use everywhere and pass data to.

This all works nicely, the passing data part anyway, but the slideshow never gets initialized and fails. Every time the page loads I get the same `"[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector"` error and the slideshow never renders.

The `slideshow.js` file is included in the head of the html document, I have tried moving this to the footer and deferred loading but the error persists.

How can I amend my code so that the slideshow is initialized when a template is loaded as I feel the issue may be trying to initiate on `$(document).ready()`.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/main-slider">
<div class="slider_wrap">
  <div id="slider">
    {{#each sliders}}
      <div class="slider_area slider0{{unbound number}}">
        <div class="slider_inner">
          <div class="inner0{{unbound number}}">
            <img {{bind-attr src="image" alt="image"}} class="nosp"/>
            <img {{bind-attr src="sm_image" alt="sm_image"}} class="sp"/>   
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    {{/each}}               
  </div>
</div>
```

slideshow.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#slider').cycle({
        slideResize:0
    });
    $('#slider').css({
        'width':'auto'
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var height = $('.slider_area').height();
        $('#slider').css("height",height + 'px');
    });
});
```

app.js

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.INDEXSLIDERS;
    }
});

// Data //

App.INDEXSLIDERS = [
    {
        number: 1,
        image: "images/sliders/index/slide1.jpg",
        sm_image: "images/sliders/index/slide1_sm.jpg"
    },
    {
        number: 2,
        image: "images/sliders/index/slide2.jpg",
        sm_image: "images/sliders/index/slide2_sm.jpg"
    },
    {
        number: 3,
        image: "images/sliders/index/slide3.jpg",
        sm_image: "images/sliders/index/slide3_sm.jpg"
    },
    {
        number: 4,
        image: "images/sliders/index/slide4.jpg",
        sm_image: "images/sliders/index/slide4_sm.jpg"
    }
];
```

**Note**

Have to add

```
slideExpr: '.slider_area'
```

to the call to `.cycle()` otherwise the plugin will try and slide the handlebar scripts inserted before and after each slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you're on the right track, document onload will happen before the page has been completely rendered.

You'll want to add that logic into the `didInsertElement` hook of the component.  Then you can scope it to that particular component instance.  Additionally I changed it from and id to a class so you can grab that instance.

#### Component

```
App.MainSliderComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    var thisSlider = this.$('.main_slider');

    thisSlider.cycle({
      slideResize:0
    });
    thisSlider.css({
        'width':'auto'
    });
    $(window).resize(function(){
        var height = thisSlider.height();
        thisSlider.css("height",height + 'px');
    });
  }
});
```

#### Template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/main-slider">
<div class="slider_wrap">
  <div class="main_slider">
    {{#each sliders}}
      <div class="slider_area slider0{{unbound number}}">
        <div class="slider_inner">
          <div class="inner0{{unbound number}}">
            <img {{bind-attr src="image" alt="image"}} class="nosp"/>
            <img {{bind-attr src="sm_image" alt="sm_image"}} class="sp"/>   
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is cycle not being included, it looks like this concept should work (I'm not familiar with cycle itself).  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hoce/1/edit